# Remover campos em branco de uma array

Tags: javascript, json

```
    for(var j =0; j<data.length; j++){
        var valorEmBranco = 0;
        for(var i =0; i<data[j].length; i++){
            var porcentagem = 0;
            var valorPorColuna = data[j][i].valor;
            //alert(valorPorColuna);
            if(data[j][i].nome ===""){
                valorEmBranco += data[j][i].valor;
            } else {
                porcentagem = (valorPorColuna / (totalDados-valorEmBranco)) * 100;
            }
            data[j][i]['porcentagem'] = porcentagem;

        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zm45Lywo/4/

Estou com problema no cálculo de porcentagem. 
Eu preciso "peneirar" os nomes em branco e retira-los do valor total para fazer o cálculo de porcentagem. Digamos que eu tenha 4253 elementos no total, eu preciso subtrair desse valor toda vez que o nome for igual a vazio (""); Ou seja, (4253-numerosEmBranco), que no caso é 12 (pelo jsfiddle)

minha array multidimensional:

```
    var data = [[{
        "nome": "SIM",
        "valor": 364
    },{
        "nome": "NÃO",
        "valor": 3877
    },{
        "nome": "",
        "valor": 12
    }]];


   porcentagem = (valorPorColuna / (totalDados-valorEmBranco)) * 100;
```

O cálculo não está dando certo. pela regra de 3, o correto para os nomes com "NÃO" = `91,41%` e está dando `91,16%`.

Comment: Não entendi, se o valor do campo nome estiver vazio não é para considerar mesmo que nesse indice tenha um valor ?

Comment: deve-se desconsiderar os valores (nomes) vazios (ou em branco). Ou seja, no total eu tenho 4253 elementos, devo desconsiderar o nomes em branco. 4253-12 = 4241. ai, eu faço a regra de 3 para a porcentagem. (não deu certo)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, se entendi direito seu problema, você pode fazer o seguinte pelo JS:

Passar o resultado por uma expressão regular de teste, e ignorar os que derem falso Ex.:

```
var patt = /^([a-zA-Z])/g
if(patt.test(nome)) { //-- se virem em branco ou qualquer coisa q não seja alfabético retorna false
   //-- seu codigo
}
```

Ps.: você pode simplificar um pouco seu for usando

```
$(data).each(function(){
   /* this é o elemento único dentro do each */
   //this.nome
   //this.valor
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Separando por passos poderia ser assim:

```
// fazer uma array simples, não multidimensional
var flat = data.reduce(function(arr, _arr) {
    return arr.concat(_arr);
}, []);

// limpar os votos vazios
var limpa = flat.filter(function(el) {
    return el.nome;
});

// contar o numero máximo
var total = limpa.reduce(function(tot, el) {
    return tot + el.valor;
}, 0);

// calcular percentagens
var percentagens = limpa.map(function(voto) {
    return {
        nome: voto.nome,
        percentagem: voto.valor * 100 / total + '%'
    };
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebxdbvrf/